# simple javascript "feature" panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a free template which has a featured Div...

www.subigya.com/test/durbarsquare

"In the Spotlight" is the featured div.

I have simple jQuery js in there to switch the images. How do I switch the heading &

related to each div in the switch. Right now, only the images switch and not the text.

The script used is feature.js and the stylesheet is style.css

Comment: with out code its tedious to help you, provide the code

Comment: He linked to the script and the broken example, is that not enough?

Answer (score 2):

From your script:

```
$("#spotlightright a").click(function(){
//these two assignments are fine, because "href" and "title" are both attributes of "a" tags
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");

//these two are not, an "a" does not have "h2" and "p" attributes
    var featureHead = $(this).attr("h2");
    var featureText = $(this).attr("p");
```

Solution: Directly reference the elements containing the text you are trying to copy over, e.g.

```
var featureHead = $('h2#example').text();
var featureText = $('p#example').text();
```

Comment: awesome !
so if that is how I reference the elements, how do I implement them after the reference ?

Comment: also since there are individual 'h3' and 'p' elements for each 'this' item, shouldn't they be in a loop?